# AngularJS Directive: display multiple times in the same page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an array with a lot of data.
I need to display it in different areas (about 10 times) in the same page (with different filtering).

To prevent long loading time (of multiple 'ng-repeat'), i'm trying to put it in a directive and show the same directive multiple times (instead of 'ng-repeat').

I want the directive to show every time it's same instance and not create new objects (and in that way to speed up the loading).
How can i get the directive to show the same instance and not create itself over and over again?

My example code:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rh78lWosr5wdeQxUhvvY?p=preview)

```
var contec = angular.module('app', [])

 .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope) {

   $scope.change = function(){
     var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 0);
     var val = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
     $rootScope.data.items[id].id = val;
  }

 $rootScope.data = {
   items: [{
     id: 1,
     name: "first"
    }, {
     id: 2,
     name: "second"
    }, {
     id: 3,
     name: "third"
    }, {
     id: 4,
     name: "forth"
  }]
}
});

contec.directive('firstDirective', function($rootScope,$compile) {
return {

replace: true,
restrict: 'EA',
scope: {
  data: '='
},
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

  var template = '';
        angular.forEach($rootScope.data.items, function(item, key) {
          var tmp = '<div second-directive data="' + key + '"></div>';

            template = template + tmp; 
         });

          element.html(template);
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
   }
   }
  });

contec.directive('secondDirective', function($rootScope,$compile) {
  var comp = function(scope,element, attrs,firstDirective){

  var index = scope.data;
  scope.item = $rootScope.data.items[index];


  var template = '<ng-include src="\'itemTemplate.html\'"></ng-include>';
    element.html(template);

    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
 }

return {
   restrict: 'EA',
   link: comp,
   scope: {
        data: '='
   },
 };
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to make your data instance available is to wrap it in a Service (specifically, a factory)

Ex:

```
contec.factory('DataFactory', function() {
    var data = {
        items: [{
            id: 1,
            name: "first"
        }, {
            id: 2,
            name: "second"
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: "third"
        }, {
            id: 4,
            name: "forth"
        }]
    }

    return {
        getData(): function() {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to inject the factory in any controller that requires it.

```
contec.controller('ExampleController', ['DataFactory', ExampleController]);

function ExampleController(DataFactory) {
    this.data = DataFactory.getData();
}
```

This approach has the added benefit of being more testable, since you can easily inject mock data in your unit tests.